# Code or Compiler error in CLANG on Raspberry Buster

Tags: c++, raspbian, clang++

I have some code reading in data from a text file and converting to float. On my new Raspberry PIs (3B+ and Zero), both running raspbian 10 Buster, I get a strange behaviour with clang++ (v 7.0.1). The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(void){

    std::string str="3.14";
    float fl = std::stof(str);

    cout << fl << endl;
    cout << fl << endl;
    cout << fl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

compiled with `clang++ -std=c++11` results in the following output:

`$ a.out
3.14
3.68935e+19
0`

Is there a fundamental error in my code or is this an issue with clang?

The issue arrises only on my new PIs, and only using clang++ (not with g++). When I change "float" to double (and "stof" to "stod") the behaviour is as expected (output three times "3.13")

**Update 18. July 2019** Seems to be resolved by an update of clang

Comment: Could you add the assembly of `main` to your question?

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug